# При создании запроса в бд по дате, джанго переводит в локальное время

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Если создаёшь запрос по дате, например:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(my_datetime_field__date=utc_today)
```

Джанга локализует время, и находит данные не с 00:00, а с 21:00 вчерашней даты.
Как изменить это поведение? Желательно для одного этого запроса.
Нужно чтобы находил данные именно за текущие сутки по gmt.

ПС: Использую postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Если  `utc_today` это `datetime`, то должно помочь `utc_today.utcnow()`

Comment: utc_today  - это дата

Comment: вообще, если планируется менять поведение django только для этого запроса, я бы его переделал на поиск `MyModel.objects.filter(my_datetime_field__gte=utc_today_00, my_datetime_field__lt=utc_tommorow_00)`, где `utc_today_00 = datetime.combine(utc_today, time()).utcnow()`, а  `utc_tommorow_00 = utc_today_00 + timedelta(hours=24)` предварительно импортировав `datetime`, `date`, `time`, `timedelta`

Comment: ну или вместо двойного фильтра поставить `mydatetime_field__range=(utc_today_00, utc_tommorow_00)`

Comment: да, я так и сделал, как выход. Просто есть же встроенные инструменты, вот и хочется научиться ими пользоваться.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего данные в БД хранятся с timezone. Подробнее https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/
Если только для этого запрос, то можно так

```py
from datetime import timedelta
MyModel.objects.filter(my_datetime_field__date=utc_today-timedelta(hours=3))
```